# Incompatible format detected with excel reading

Tags: python, maven, apache-spark, pyspark

Hi everyone I am trying to read .xlsx with spark. Here is the code:

```
spark_df3 = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", True) \
    .option("dataAddress", "MyList") \
    .load("https://url_from_blob_storage")
```

However i get the error:

> AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected.

The version of crealytics.spark is 0.13.5 so there is no problem in format parameter.
Finally, I tried reading excel with pandas (with xlrd as engine) and it works perfectly, but unfortunately I need to write spark dataframe exactly to sql tables.

```
pd_df = pd.read_excel("https://url_from_blob_storage")
spark_df2=spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
```

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong in spark.read ?

Full stack trace:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <command-1235026629993988> in <module>
         21 # <class 'pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame'>
         22 # <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
    ---> 23 spark_df3 = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
         24     .option("header", "true") \
         25     .option("inferSchema", True) \
    
    /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
        156         self.options(**options)
        157         if isinstance(path, str):
    --> 158             return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
        159         elif path is not None:
        160             if type(path) != list:
    
    /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1302 
       1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    -> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
       1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1306 
    
    /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
        121                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
        122                 # JVM exception message.
    --> 123                 raise converted from None
        124             else:
        125                 raise
    
    AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected.
    
    A transaction log for Databricks Delta was found at `You must use
'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table.`,
    but you are trying to read from `https://url_from_blob_storage` using format("com.crealytics.spark.excel"). You must use
    'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table.
    
    To disable this check, SET spark.databricks.delta.formatCheck.enabled=false
    To learn more about Delta, see https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/index
```

Comment: please show the full stacktrace, especially the lines starting with "Caused by"

Comment: @AlexOtt Hi! Added the trace. Why does it say "You must use
'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed it first, but really you need to replace `https://url_from_blob_storage` with the correct URL - either `abfss` or `wasbs` (on Azure) or, `s3://bucket/path` (on AWS). It should be something like this: `abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data-inside-container>`.

See [Databricks documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage#direct-access-using-abfs-uri-for-blob-storage-or-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2) for that.

P.S. Really, error is misleading

Comment: I guess this is really it. Currently my link looks like https://storage_accounts/container/folder/file?SAS_TOKEN_STR. I will come back later when I receive abfss or wasbs from my Azure admins and if it works mark your answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: if you have SAS token already, then you can use it as described in the docs. you just need to construct correct ABFSS URL out of it